# Figure out a curve given its torsion and curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I am given a torsion and curvature, and I have to give a parametrization for the curve with those characteristics. How can I do that? For example:
$$\kappa (t)=\frac{t}{1+t^2}\quad \quad \tau(t)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+t^2}$$
Where $\kappa$ is the curvature and $\tau$ the torsion

Comment: you have to solve the Serre - Frenet relations